# Coreaudiod spams system log: Enabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is inactive

Tags: macos, audio

I'm getting my system log virtually spammed with:

```
May 13 23:56:36 alluminium coreaudiod[238]: Enabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is inactive
May 13 23:56:37 alluminium coreaudiod[238]: Disabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is active
May 13 23:56:38 alluminium coreaudiod[238]: Enabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is inactive
May 13 23:56:39 alluminium coreaudiod[238]: Disabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is active
May 13 23:56:39 alluminium coreaudiod[238]: Enabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is inactive
May 13 23:56:39 alluminium coreaudiod[238]: Disabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is active
May 13 23:56:39 alluminium coreaudiod[238]: Enabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is inactive
May 13 23:56:41 alluminium coreaudiod[238]: Disabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is active
May 13 23:56:41 alluminium coreaudiod[238]: Enabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is inactive
May 13 23:56:42 alluminium coreaudiod[238]: Disabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is active
```

Googling yields no useful results. Any ideas what this is and how to alleviate it?

Comment: I am receiving this as well. It seems to have started on 10.8.4 12E47 beta build for me. I did narrow down that it is logging in system.log whenever Mac OS X makes a sound action. Have not yet found a fix, but I don't notice any issue with my system, e.g. slow-down, glitches, etc.

Comment: Which version of the OS? @booyah please do not discuss confidential pre-release software.

Comment: @GrahamPerrin: you're right, I should probably ditch the whole topic, since I'm on a pre-release as well. Didn't think well enough before posting.

Comment: It's an honest mistake, easily made ;-) Also it's possible that these messages from coreaudiod are in a release, but so rare that they're not yet found by Google. I reckon, leave this question open for a week or so (WWDC in around a week) …

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that 10.8.4 is released (build 12E55), it is still there. I've gotten a response from Apple Engineering that this is logged by design.

Comment: by design? intentionally annoying people?

Comment: Yes by design. it's a Notice level log message. Add this to /etc/asl.conf stop loging them:
? [= Sender coreaudiod] [> Level warning] ignore

Answer (score 2):

As best I can tell, these are purely diagnostic messages and don't indicate a specific failure and instead are just logging state changes for the audio subsystem.

If you wish to suppress those messages to have a clean log, it's quite easy to modify the logging system to not log specific or general messages for certain subsystems. Just edit your question if you don't know how to configure `syslog.conf` or ask a follow on question if that's your true aim separate from knowing that these are placed there by design.

You can also reduce the volume of these messages by determining which programs you are running that call the audio subsystem so often. If you log out of all accounts, you can convince yourself that the log only is reporting actions that your user level software is causing instead of some lower level system event that you cannot control.

Comment: The messages are level 5 (notice).

Comment: One particular culprit I've found is Spotify; it seems to keep the audio system active at all times, whether it's playing or not. That causes a pair of these log messages every minute.

Answer (score 1):

On build 12E55, I've also been seeing these messages. At first, I downgraded coreaudiod back to 10.8.3's version but after playing with `strings` and `dtruss`, I found a way to stop the flood of these messages on my system with the latest coreaudiod (you still see the message once when coreaudiod starts but only then). Here is what you can try:

1. Create `/Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.ServerSettings.plist` with the following content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
       <key>AllowStackShotsDuringIO</key>
       <true/>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
2. Reboot.

Comment: Consider the possibility that allowing stackshots may be disruptive.

Comment: Fair enough, but given that the log here indicates the stackshots are happening very often anyway, I'd rather take my chances and have coreaudio do what it was going to do without logging it.

Comment: I guess that enabling automatic stackshots simply allows the system to be prepared for the automation. I doubt that a stackshot occurs every time automation is enabled.

Comment: You're right and I didn't realise that when reading the message. I won't delete this as I believe it should be for someone to decide whether the trade-off is worth it for them personally, but my post shouldn't be considered as an answer.